# Ao subir o site dá erro de: failure to load a file

Tags: javascript, asp.net, iis, pdf

Quando eu subo o site me dá esse erro:

> GET http://localhost:3000/locale/locale.properties 404 (Not
>   Found)xhrLoadText
>   @ l10n.js:128parseResource
>   @ l10n.js:257L10nResourceLink.load
>   @ l10n.js:350loadLocale
>   @l10n.js:363document.webL10n.undefined.setLanguage
>   @l10n.js:997webViewerInitialized
>   @ viewer.js:7081 l10n.js:351
>   http://localhost:3000/locale/locale.properties not found.

Acontece que o arquivo

> locale/locale.properties

Eu tenho em meu projeto e não sei porque o erro:

> Not Found(404)

Esses arquivos eu baixei do PDF.js, sugerido por um colega em outro post. O que eu baixo funciona, mas quando eu adiciono em meu projeto então dá esse erro. Estou tentando ver alguma dependência que eu não coloquei, mas aparentemente está tudo OK(claro que não está), mas não consigo ver onde está o problema. Se alguém usa ou já usou o PDF.js e puder me dar uma ajuda, eu agradeço. Não sei se é alguma configuração no IIS, enfim, estou sem saber o que fazer.

Esta é a função js que dá esse erro:

```
function xhrLoadText(url, onSuccess, onFailure) {
    onSuccess = onSuccess || function _onSuccess(data) {};
    onFailure = onFailure || function _onFailure() {
      console.warn(url + ' not found.');
    };

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, gAsyncResourceLoading);
    if (xhr.overrideMimeType) {
      xhr.overrideMimeType('text/plain; charset=utf-8');
    }
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
        if (xhr.status == 200 || xhr.status === 0) {
          onSuccess(xhr.responseText);
        } else {
          onFailure();
        }
      }
    };
    xhr.onerror = onFailure;
    xhr.ontimeout = onFailure;

    // in Firefox OS with the app:// protocol, trying to XHR a non-existing
    // URL will raise an exception here -- hence this ugly try...catch.
    try {
      xhr.send(null); **//Aqui dá o erro**
    } catch (e) {
      onFailure();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Faltou o Mime Type do locale.properties. Fiz text/plain para .properties e não deu mais o erro. Não mostra o PDF, mas isso será outro post caso eu não resolva.